# Is it ok to call deleteObject: on object's own managedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

To delete an object `o` from core data, is it ok to use the object's own reference to the managed object context `managedObjectContext`?

```
[o.managedObjectContext deleteObject:o];
```

Comment: Could you try it! I'm also want to know what happened :D

Comment: @nikhil84 your edit was totally wrong and out of the way. Please do NOT abuse your edit power like that. Thanks. Explanation: first, never **add** salutations. We should remove them, if anything, not add them. Second, **do not change code**! The OP got every right to use whatever variable names he/she like.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Ok thanks for the update and your points are appreciate but first, what's wrong with salutations? As we always say thank you for help. Second, from code perspective we should help OP to use better variable names which would help them in going towards better practice.

Comment: @nikhil84 regarding salutation, read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). At first I was also against this,  but then realized Stack Overflow isn't a social forum, so those things are indeed just "noise". As for code, you're totally right but the correct approach is by leaving a comment, or mentioning it in an answer. Anyway, if you want to discuss it further feel free to create a chat room and invite me. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I got your point regarding the salutation. Also for code practice I would leave a comment or within my answer/comment to user.

Comment: @nikhil84 cheers, I'm really glad you understand. Keep up the good job! :)

Answer (score 2):

The apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008286-SW4) says its ok.

Explanation:

- On calling `deleteObject:` on a `managedObjectContext`, we mark the object to be deleted from the `managedObjectContext`. The actual deletion occurs when we call `save:` on the context.
- The above statement `[o.managedObjectContext deleteObject:o]` actually tells the compiler to send the message `deleteObject:` to the object `o.managedObjectContext` which is valid even after deletion of `o`.

Comment: Then why did you ask this question :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can delete object in this manner, but you have to do save after deletion.

```
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:thisItem];

NSError *savingError;

if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError]){
    NSLog(@"saved Ok");
}else{
    NSLog(@"error %@", savingError);
}
```